# Slick way to combine two arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a situation where I have one array like this:

```
//[itemId] => [agentId]

[123] => [1qa2ws]
[456] => [3ed4rf]
```

And other:

```
// array of agents with full objects inside

[0] => [id => 1qa2ws, ....]
[1] => [id => 3ed4rf, ....]
```

So now I would like to combine this in a way that I can tell "okay, if ID from the agent array is the same as the value of the first array, apply the whole object to it instead of what now is only the ID".

I have a 'dirty' solution:

```
foreach ($agentIDs as &$agentID){
    foreach ($resolvedAgents as $agent){
        if($agent['accountId'] == $agentID){
            $agentID = $agent;
        }
    }
}
```

The order of two arrays doesn't have to be the same, so the first array position of the first array isn't necessarily the same agent as the first agent in the agent array.

I would like to end up with:

```
[123] => [id => 1qa2ws, ....]
[456] => [id => 3ed4rf, ....]
```

Is there some cleaner solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up doing this, which is the solution I am happy with:

```
$agents = array_map(function($agent) use ($resolvedAgents){
    return $resolvedAgents[array_search($agent, array_column($resolvedAgents, 'accountId'))] ?: null;
}, $agentIDs);
```

Basically returning item from the second array from the position where it is found.

Comment: You're right, I got it right the first time, changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about `array_combine`?

```
$result = array_combine($array1, $array2)
```

[PHPDoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `array_combine()` combines the fixed order of array values, which is not the case here

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$a = array();
$a[123] = ['1qa2ws'];
$a[456] = ['3ed4rf'];

$b = array();
$b[0] = ['id' => '1qa2ws', 'other' => 'data'];
$b[1] = ['id' => '3ed4rf', 'other' => 'data'];
$b[2] = ['id' => 'av42sa', 'other' => 'data'];

$c = array_reduce($a, function ($carry, $item) use ($a, $b) {
    $itemId = array_search($item, $a);
    $agentId = array_values($item)[0];

    if (array_search($agentId, array_column($b, 'id')) !== false) {
        $carry[$itemId] = $b[array_search($agentId, array_column($b, 'id'))];
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$resolvedAgents = array_combine(array_column($resolvedAgents, 'id'), $resolvedAgents);
```

After that $resolvedAgents will become:

```
[1qa2ws] => [id => 1qa2ws, ....]
[3ed4rf] => [id => 3ed4rf, ....]
```

And also u will have your first array:

```
// [itemId] => [agentId]
[123] => [1qa2ws]
[456] => [3ed4rf]
```

If u need just a single array at the the end then:

```
$agents = array_map(function($agentId) use ($resolvedAgents) {
    return $resolvedAgents[$agentId] ?: null;
}, $agentIDs);
```

At the end your code will be:

```
$resolvedAgents = array_combine(array_column($resolvedAgents, 'id'), $resolvedAgents);
$agents = array_map(function($agentId) use ($resolvedAgents) {
    return $resolvedAgents[$agentId] ?: null;
}, $agentIDs);
```